# Gulp ngmin + uglify not working properly

Tags: angularjs, uglifyjs, gulp, ngmin

I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src(['app/js/app.js', 'app/config/config.js', 'app/js/controllers.js', 'app/js/directives.js' , 'app/js/filters.js',  'app/js/footer.js',
                 'app/js/guideTour.js', 'app/js/mobileBanner.js', 'app/js/services.js', 'app/js/youtube.js', 'app/js/dataSync.js', 'app/js/addthis.js'])
//.pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
.pipe(ngmin())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'))
.pipe(livereload(server))
.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

The problem is that the concatenated file which is also the output of ngmin(), is working fine, but after uglifying the code, something breaks, and I get the [following error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e).

With no specific indicator where to start debugging.

Stack trace:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:6:449
at http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:32:125
at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:30:200)
at http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:32:193
at c (http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:30:200)
at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:30:417)
at http://localhost:8000/angular/angular-route.min.js:10:302
at Object.q [as forEach] (http://localhost:8000/angular/angular.min.js:7:380)
at http://localhost:8000/angular/angular-route.min.js:10:248
```

Comment: Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Solution was running uglify task with [mangle](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglify) option set to false.
ie: `.uglify({mangle: false})`

whole code:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() { 
return gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
.pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
.pipe(ngmin())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'))
.pipe(livereload(server))
.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549029/angular-js-injectormodulerr-failed-to-instantiate-module-with-mangle/23762068#23762068

Comment: My only issue with that is that I need to set specifically to not mangle the main factory and module names in angular but still uglify all the bower scripts. I do not see a way to specify what to mangle and what not to without having to write a new task, one for the bower components and one for every other script.

Answer (score 10):

You don`t need to set mangle to false, you can just use [ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate) and call on your gulpfile.js like this:

```
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate')
...
gulp.task('scripts', function() { 
return gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
.pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
.pipe(ngmin())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(ngAnnotate())
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'))
.pipe(livereload(server))
.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

works on my projects for app on a single file